# Use react-native created an application installation package big size

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I used react-native, expo, native-base & typescript. I created a simple function inside my application. After installing I found size of the application was too large, I don't know why, what should I do to make it more concise or smaller?

Comment: React-native hase create apk in multiple format, so apk size become large. Have you try it for reduce size of APK with the help of this DOC. https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expo adds a lot of extra size to the apk. If you can eject from expo: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md